# The expression doesn't evaluate to a function but another expression is able

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Here i have to create functions for inserting data into the firebase database, but my first function got error while another works fine, im not sure what is wrong, the error exists at the create(customer , im not sure what is wrong

The expression doesn't evaluate to a function, so it can't be invoked.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:hupcarwashcustomer/extensions.dart';
import 'package:hupcarwashcustomer/user_model/customer.dart';
import 'package:hupcarwashcustomer/validation.dart';

class registerCustomer extends StatefulWidget {
  const registerCustomer({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<registerCustomer> createState() => _registerCustomerState();
}

class _registerCustomerState extends State<registerCustomer> {
  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController nameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController contactController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController userNameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController icController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController conPassController = TextEditingController();
  final GlobalKey<FormState> registerEmployee = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  void dispose() {
    emailController.dispose();
    nameController.dispose();
    userNameController.dispose();
    contactController.dispose();
    icController.dispose();
    passController.dispose();
    conPassController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Register Employee", style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Lato', fontSize: 22),),
          backgroundColor: '03045E'.toColor(),
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(40),
            child: Form(
              key: registerEmployee,
              child: Card(
                color: 'CAF0F8'.toColor(),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(30),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      TextFormField(
                        style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonSemi', fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
                        inputFormatters: [LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(25),],
                        controller: emailController,
                        decoration:  InputDecoration(
                          errorMaxLines: 2,
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: '03045E'.toColor(),
                          errorStyle: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonSemi', fontSize: 12, ),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10), ),
                          hintText: "Email",
                          hintStyle: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonSemi', fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),),
                        validator: (value){
                          if(!emailValidation.hasMatch(value!) && value.isNotEmpty){
                            return 'Email correct format should be xxxxx@xxx.com';
                          }else if(value.isEmpty){
                            return 'Please enter your email';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      TextFormField(
                        style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonSemi', fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
                        inputFormatters: [LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(20),],
                        controller: nameController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          errorMaxLines: 2,
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: '03045E'.toColor(),
                          errorStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonSemi', fontSize: 12, ),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10), ),
                          hintText: "Username",
                          hintStyle: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonSemi', fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        validator: (value){
                          if(value!.length < 5 && value.isNotEmpty){
                            return 'Your username cant be that short';
                          }else if(value.isEmpty){
                            return 'Please enter your username';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      TextFormField(
                        style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonSemi', fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
                        inputFormatters: [LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(20),],
                        controller: nameController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          errorMaxLines: 2,
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: '03045E'.toColor(),
                          errorStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonSemi', fontSize: 12, ),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10), ),
                          hintText: "Name",
                          hintStyle: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonSemi', fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        validator: (value){
                          if(value!.length < 5 && value.isNotEmpty){
                            return 'Your name cant be that short';
                          }else if(value.isEmpty){
                            return 'Please enter your name';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      TextFormField(
                        style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonSemi', fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
                        inputFormatters: [LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(14),],
                        controller: icController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: '03045E'.toColor(),
                          errorStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonSemi', fontSize: 12, ),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10), ),
                          hintText: 'IC',
                          hintStyle: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonSemi', fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),),
                        validator: (value){
                          if(!icValidation.hasMatch(value!) && value.isNotEmpty){
                            return 'IC correct format should be xxxxxx-xx-xxxx';
                          }else if(value.isEmpty){
                            return 'Please enter your ic';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      TextFormField(
                        style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonSemi', fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
                        inputFormatters: [LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(12),],
                        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                        controller: contactController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          errorMaxLines: 2,
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: '03045E'.toColor(),
                          errorStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonSemi', fontSize: 12, ),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10), ),
                          hintText: 'Contact No.',
                          hintStyle: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonSemi', fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),),
                        validator: (value){
                          if(!phoneValidation.hasMatch(value!) && value.isNotEmpty){
                            return 'Phone correct format should be numbers';
                          }else if(value.isEmpty){
                            return 'Please enter your phone number';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      TextFormField(
                        style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonSemi', fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
                        inputFormatters: [LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(15),],
                        controller: passController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          errorMaxLines: 2,
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: '03045E'.toColor(),
                          errorStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonSemi', fontSize: 12, ),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10), ),
                          hintText: 'Password',
                          hintStyle: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonSemi', fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),),
                        validator: (value){
                          if(value!.length <= 8 && value.isNotEmpty){
                            return 'Password should at least be 8 characters long';
                          }else if(value.isEmpty){
                            return 'Please enter your password';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 15,
                      ),
                      TextFormField(
                        style: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonSemi', fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),
                        inputFormatters: [LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(15),],
                        controller: conPassController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          errorMaxLines: 2,
                          filled: true,
                          fillColor: '03045E'.toColor(),
                          errorStyle: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonSemi', fontSize: 12, ),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10), ),
                          hintText: 'Con Password',
                          hintStyle: const TextStyle(fontFamily: 'MonSemi', fontSize: 16, color: Colors.white),),
                        validator: (value){
                          if(value! != passController.text && value.isNotEmpty){
                            return 'Confirm password not same with password';
                          }else if(value.isEmpty){
                            return 'Please enter your confirm password';
                          }
                          return null;
                        },

                      ),
                      const SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: 180, height: 50,
                        child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: () async{
                          if(!registerEmployee.currentState!.validate()){
                            return;
                          }else{
                            bool userAuth = false, nameAuth = false, contactAuth = false, emailAuth = false,icAuth = false;

                            //check email
                            final QuerySnapshot admin = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Admin")
                                .where("email", isEqualTo: emailController.text).limit(1).get();
                            final List<DocumentSnapshot> adminCheck = admin.docs;
                            final QuerySnapshot Employee = await FirebaseFirestore
                                .instance.collection("Employee")
                                .where("email", isEqualTo: emailController.text).limit(1).get();
                            final List<DocumentSnapshot> employCheck = Employee.docs;
                            final QuerySnapshot customer = await FirebaseFirestore
                                .instance.collection("Customer")
                                .where("email", isEqualTo: emailController.text).limit(1).get();
                            final List<DocumentSnapshot> custCheck = customer.docs;
                            if (custCheck.isNotEmpty || adminCheck.isNotEmpty || employCheck.isNotEmpty) {
                              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                                  content: Text('email has been taken')));
                            } else if (custCheck.isEmpty && adminCheck.isEmpty && employCheck.isEmpty) {
                              emailAuth = true;
                            }

                            final QuerySnapshot AdminUser = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Admin")
                                .where("userName", isEqualTo: userNameController.text).limit(1).get();
                            final List<DocumentSnapshot> adminUser = AdminUser.docs;
                            final QuerySnapshot EmployeeUser = await FirebaseFirestore
                                .instance.collection("Employee")
                                .where("userName", isEqualTo: userNameController.text).limit(1).get();
                            final List<DocumentSnapshot> employUser = EmployeeUser.docs;
                            final QuerySnapshot CustomerUser = await FirebaseFirestore
                                .instance.collection("Customer")
                                .where("userName", isEqualTo: userNameController.text).limit(1).get();
                            final List<DocumentSnapshot> custUser = CustomerUser.docs;
                            if (custUser.isNotEmpty || adminUser.isNotEmpty || employUser.isNotEmpty) {
                              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                                  content: Text('Username has been taken')));
                            } else if (custUser.isEmpty && adminUser.isEmpty && employUser.isEmpty) {
                              userAuth = true;
                            }

                            final QuerySnapshot AdminName = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Admin")
                                .where("name", isEqualTo: nameController.text).limit(1).get();
                            final List<DocumentSnapshot> adminName = AdminName.docs;
                            final QuerySnapshot EmployeeName = await FirebaseFirestore
                                .instance.collection("Employee")
                                .where("name", isEqualTo: nameController.text).limit(1).get();
                            final List<DocumentSnapshot> employName = EmployeeName.docs;
                            final QuerySnapshot CustomerName = await FirebaseFirestore
                                .instance.collection("Customer")
                                .where("name", isEqualTo: nameController.text).limit(1).get();
                            final List<DocumentSnapshot> custName = CustomerName.docs;
                            if (custName.isNotEmpty || adminName.isNotEmpty || employName.isNotEmpty) {
                              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                                  content: Text('email has been taken')));
                            } else if (custName.isEmpty && adminName.isEmpty && employName.isEmpty) {
                              nameAuth = true;
                            }

                            final QuerySnapshot AdminIC = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Admin")
                                .where("ic", isEqualTo: icController.text).limit(1).get();
                            final List<DocumentSnapshot> adminIC = AdminIC .docs;
                            final QuerySnapshot EmployeeIC  = await FirebaseFirestore
                                .instance.collection("Employee")
                                .where("ic", isEqualTo: icController.text).limit(1).get();
                            final List<DocumentSnapshot> employIC  = EmployeeIC.docs;
                            final QuerySnapshot CustomerIC  = await FirebaseFirestore
                                .instance.collection("Customer")
                                .where("ic", isEqualTo: icController.text).limit(1).get();
                            final List<DocumentSnapshot> custIC  = CustomerIC .docs;
                            if (custIC.isNotEmpty || adminIC.isNotEmpty || employIC.isNotEmpty) {
                              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                                  content: Text('ic has exist in the database')));
                            } else if (custIC.isEmpty && adminIC.isEmpty && employIC.isEmpty) {
                              icAuth = true;
                            }

                            final QuerySnapshot AdminContact = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Admin")
                                .where("contact", isEqualTo: contactController.text).limit(1).get();
                            final List<DocumentSnapshot> adminContact = AdminContact.docs;
                            final QuerySnapshot EmployeeContact  = await FirebaseFirestore
                                .instance.collection("Employee")
                                .where("contact", isEqualTo: contactController.text).limit(1).get();
                            final List<DocumentSnapshot> employContact  = EmployeeContact.docs;
                            final QuerySnapshot CustomerContact  = await FirebaseFirestore
                                .instance.collection("Customer")
                                .where("contact", isEqualTo: contactController.text).limit(1).get();
                            final List<DocumentSnapshot> custContact  = CustomerContact.docs;
                            if (custContact.isNotEmpty || adminContact.isNotEmpty || employContact.isNotEmpty) {
                              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                                  content: Text('ic has exist in the database')));
                            } else if (custContact.isEmpty && adminContact.isEmpty && employContact.isEmpty) {
                              contactAuth = true;
                            }

                            if (nameAuth && emailAuth && icAuth
                                && contactAuth && userAuth) {
                              FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                                  email: emailController.text,
                                  password: passController.text).then((value) {
                                create(customer(
                                    email: emailController.text,
                                    name: nameController.text,
                                    ic: icController.text,
                                    userName: userNameController.text,
                                    contact: contactController.text));
                                Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName(Navigator.defaultRouteName));
                              }).onError((error, stackTrace){
                                print("${error.toString()}");
                              });
                            }

                          }

                        }, child: Text('Register', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Lato', fontSize: 18))),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  static Future create(customer cust) async {
    final userCollection = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("Customer")
        .doc(cust.email.toString());
    final newService = customer(
        email: cust.email,
        ic: cust.ic,
        name: cust.name,
        contact: cust.contact,
        userName: cust.userName,)
        .toJson();
    try {
      await userCollection.set(newService);
    } catch (e) {
      print("some error occured $e");
    }
  }
}





 child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: () async{
                          if(!registerEmployee.currentState!.validate()){
                            return;
                          }else{
                            bool nameAuth = false, contactAuth = false, emailAuth = false,icAuth = false;
                            //check email
                              final QuerySnapshot admin = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Admin")
                                  .where("email", isEqualTo: emailController.text).limit(1).get();
                              final List<DocumentSnapshot> adminCheck = admin.docs;
                              final QuerySnapshot Employee = await FirebaseFirestore
                                  .instance.collection("Employee")
                                  .where("email", isEqualTo: emailController.text).limit(1).get();
                              final List<DocumentSnapshot> employCheck = Employee.docs;
                              final QuerySnapshot customer = await FirebaseFirestore
                                  .instance.collection("Customer")
                                  .where("email", isEqualTo: emailController.text).limit(1).get();
                              final List<DocumentSnapshot> custCheck = customer.docs;
                              if (custCheck.isNotEmpty || adminCheck.isNotEmpty || employCheck.isNotEmpty) {
                                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                                    content: Text('email has been taken')));
                              } else if (custCheck.isEmpty && adminCheck.isEmpty && employCheck.isEmpty) {
                                emailAuth = true;
                              }

                              //check name validation
                            final QuerySnapshot AdminName = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Admin")
                                .where("name", isEqualTo: nameController.text).limit(1).get();
                            final List<DocumentSnapshot> adminName = AdminName.docs;
                            final QuerySnapshot EmployeeName = await FirebaseFirestore
                                .instance.collection("Employee")
                                .where("name", isEqualTo: nameController.text).limit(1).get();
                            final List<DocumentSnapshot> employName = EmployeeName.docs;
                            final QuerySnapshot CustomerName = await FirebaseFirestore
                                .instance.collection("Customer")
                                .where("name", isEqualTo: nameController.text).limit(1).get();
                            final List<DocumentSnapshot> custName = CustomerName.docs;
                            if (custName.isNotEmpty || adminName.isNotEmpty || employName.isNotEmpty) {
                              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                                  content: Text('email has been taken')));
                            } else if (custName.isEmpty && adminName.isEmpty && employName.isEmpty) {
                              nameAuth = true;
                            }

                            //check ic
                            final QuerySnapshot AdminIC = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Admin")
                                .where("ic", isEqualTo: icController.text).limit(1).get();
                            final List<DocumentSnapshot> adminIC = AdminIC .docs;
                            final QuerySnapshot EmployeeIC  = await FirebaseFirestore
                                .instance.collection("Employee")
                                .where("ic", isEqualTo: icController.text).limit(1).get();
                            final List<DocumentSnapshot> employIC  = EmployeeIC.docs;
                            final QuerySnapshot CustomerIC  = await FirebaseFirestore
                                .instance.collection("Customer")
                                .where("ic", isEqualTo: icController.text).limit(1).get();
                            final List<DocumentSnapshot> custIC  = CustomerIC .docs;
                            if (custIC.isNotEmpty || adminIC.isNotEmpty || employIC.isNotEmpty) {
                              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                                  content: Text('ic has exist in the database')));
                            } else if (custIC.isEmpty && adminIC.isEmpty && employIC.isEmpty) {
                              icAuth = true;
                            }


                            final QuerySnapshot AdminContact = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Admin")
                                .where("contact", isEqualTo: contactController.text).limit(1).get();
                            final List<DocumentSnapshot> adminContact = AdminContact.docs;
                            final QuerySnapshot EmployeeContact  = await FirebaseFirestore
                                .instance.collection("Employee")
                                .where("contact", isEqualTo: contactController.text).limit(1).get();
                            final List<DocumentSnapshot> employContact  = EmployeeContact.docs;
                            final QuerySnapshot CustomerContact  = await FirebaseFirestore
                                .instance.collection("Customer")
                                .where("contact", isEqualTo: contactController.text).limit(1).get();
                            final List<DocumentSnapshot> custContact  = CustomerContact.docs;
                            if (custContact.isNotEmpty || adminContact.isNotEmpty || employContact.isNotEmpty) {
                              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(
                                  content: Text('ic has exist in the database')));
                            } else if (custContact.isEmpty && adminContact.isEmpty && employContact.isEmpty) {
                              contactAuth = true;
                            }


                            if (nameAuth && emailAuth && icAuth
                                && contactAuth ) {
                              FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                                  email: emailController.text,
                                  password: passController.text).then((value) {
                                create(employee(
                                    email: emailController.text,
                                    name: nameController.text,
                                    ic: icController.text,
                                    contact: contactController.text));
                                Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName(Navigator.defaultRouteName));
                              }).onError((error, stackTrace){
                                print("${error.toString()}");
                              });
                            }
                          }
                        },
                            child: Text('Register', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Lato', fontSize: 18))),
                      ),
```

Comment: can you add more code about you implemented those functions, and where did you called them ?

Comment: i call them at the same page, like one is customer register page and another one is employee register page